# postgres Query update decimal increment + 1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I Need to Build a query to update a certain field  need to increment the last number of a decimal number stored as a `varchar`:

```
'1481126826.2363343' => '1481126826.2363344'
```

```
UPDATE callcenter.chamada_agente 
  SET uniqueid = SUM('1481126826.2363343' + 1) 
WHERE id_chamada_agente = 32408
```

Is possible to be done in postgresql? if not I can do this in my java code too.

-- UPDATED QUESTION ---

Big problem: uniqueid is VARCHAR, and my postgres version is 9.2

Comment: So the number is actually some variable? Be careful to not mistakenly use a floating point type variable. Or do you want to add 1^x to the uniqueid already present? Then again, this column should not be of floating point type. And anyway, you should never update IDs.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: it's not a floating point. It's even worse: it's a varchar

Comment: yeah its a VARCHAR, and my postgres version is 9.2

Comment: That doesn't sound too complicated. The algorithm: Remember the dot position, remove the dot from the string, cast to bigint, add one, cast to string, insert the dot. Now look up the string functions needed and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
UPDATE callcenter.chamada_agente 
  SET uniqueid = '1481126826.2363343'::decimal+0.0000001
WHERE id_chamada_agente = 32408
```

I'm converting uniqueid to decimal using "::" just for the operation, tested it on my own db and the result was '1481126826.2363344'.